# Windows mobile msi installation file fails

Tags: windows-mobile, installation, windows-installer, cab

I have a Windows Mobile Professional 6.1 CF 2.0 application, I created a windows installation package with this link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158529.aspx

My .ini file is:

```
[CEAppManager]
Version = 1.0
Component = netcf.core.ppc3.armv4.cab
[netcf.core.ppc3.armv4.cab]
Description =  installation module
CabFiles = Mobile.cab
```

but it doesn't work. It builds the msi file successfully, but when I click the msi file it installs the application to my PC rather than to my mobile phone (which is connected to the PC via WM device center).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSI should contain a CAB that is copied and launched on the mobile device. From this point, you have to continue the installation on your mobile device. Maybe this worked but you did forget to check the device for further installation steps.

Comment: I see nothing on the phone, it just installs my cab file and dlls to my PC.